# How to call one function return value to another function

Tags: python

Below is the dictionary

`[{'id':1,'name':'A','revenue':1234,'values':[1,2,3,4]}, {'id':2,'name':'B','revenue':5678,'values':[5,6,7,8]} {'id':3,'name':'C','revenue':1232,'values':[1,2,3,2]} {'id':4,'name':'D','revenue':1221,'values':[1,2,2,1]}]`

Code is below

```
def fn1(elements):
    data = {'id':None,'name':None}
    return data

def fn2(elements):
    test = {'revenue':'None','details':None}
    return test
```

in fn2 `details` has to come from `fn1` return.

can i write like `test['details'] = fn1(elements)`.

I am getting `AttributeError`

Is it possible or do i need to again the write the details logic?

Comment: See how to create a [mre]. Also, please always include the **complete** error traceback, there is usually not much we can do with just the name of the error.

Comment: are you expecting `test` to have a value of `{'revenue': 'None', 'details': {'id': None, 'name': None}}` ?

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes i am looking the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def fn2(elements):
    test = {'revenue':'None','details': fn1(elements)}
    return test
```

Try if this works

Answer (score -1):

```
def fn2(elements):
    test = {'revenue':'None','details':fn1()}
    return test
```

Please note that have declared that the functions take a parameter (argument elements) however you do not use it so you should remove it